# Draw shape by inverting colors in Processing

Tags: processing

I want to draw circles in Processing not by drawing circles of a specific color, per se, but by inverting each pixel each circle occupies. The following is the effect I'm going for:

[image: circles drawn by described inversion method]

Besides keeping track of a matrix of pixel values, is there any way to efficiently achieve these aims in Processing, hopefully with built-in functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to easily achieve that by setting the [blendMode()](https://processing.org/reference/blend_.html) to `DIFFERENCE`:

```
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  //change blend mode to difference
  blendMode(DIFFERENCE);
  //draw circles
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
    float diameter = random(50,200);
    ellipse(random(width * .35,width * .65),random(height * .2,height * .8),diameter,diameter);
  }
}
//the code bellow is just to redraw on click
void draw(){}
void mouseReleased(){
  setup();
}
```

Here's a preview:

[image: circles with difference blend mode]

you can actually run a quick demo bellow (click to redraw):

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  //change blend mode to difference
  blendMode(DIFFERENCE);
  //draw circles
  for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
    var diameter = random(50,200);
    ellipse(random(width * .35,width * .65),random(height * .2,height * .8),diameter,diameter);
  }
}
//the code bellow is just to redraw on click
function draw(){}
function mouseReleased(){
  setup();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```